# How to get json from android to server - Django

Tags: android, json, django

My doubt is that, how can I receive a **json data** or **json string** which is sent by an **Android app** to my Django cloud server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Which is better, **REST** or **non-REST** ?

Comment: depends upon your use cases, these days people generally use **REST** and the link I have provided is for **REST**.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the json data send to the django app, inside `request.body`

```
import json
def android_backend(request):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    # do the processing
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

Comment: Can I test your code without establishing connection between  Android App and Cloud Server ? If possible, then how it could be?